# How to make a desktop (with two network cards) as a router

Tags: networking, router

I have a win 10 machine(A) with 2 network cards. While I have only one Ethernet port at my work place, and recently I got another machine(B). What I want to do is to connect machine A with the first network cart to the Ethernet port, and connect machine B with the second network card to machine B.

So I configured machine A (Win 10) as follows:

```
[NIC1]: 
IP: 202.3.4.136
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 202.3.4.1

[NIC2]: 
IP: 192.168.1.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 202.3.4.136
```

I configure machine B as follows:

```
[NIC1]: 
IP: 192.168.1.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

It's possible to ping machine B from machine A, and vice versa. However I cannot access the internet from machine B. So I tried to use the method mentioned [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/40069-42-using-router-networks), adding `route add -p 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1` on machine A. It still does not work. What is the problem for that? Thank you!

The network topology looks like this:

```
[port to Internet] <------> (NIC1) Machine A (NIC2) <------> (NIC1) Machine B
```

Comment: If you create a new network on the other side of your PC, you will need to let its router know about that network, otherwise it will drop packets destined for that network, or it will forward those packets to its default route (probably the Internet) instead of sending them to your PC. Routers learn routes in three ways: directly connected networks, statically defined routes, or through routing protocols with other routers. The work router has no knowledge of the network on the other side of your PC unless you somehow tell it to send traffic destined for that network to your PC.

Comment: I print the route on machine A. It's like:           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     202.3.4.1     default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   202.3.4.136     default
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.1       1

Comment: Not machine A, but the gateway of machine A doesn't know how to send traffic destined for the other side of machine A to machine A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Win10, you could just turn on the Internet Connection Sharing on the public NIC, then set the corresponding IP of the following private NICs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell machine B to use 192.168.0.1 as default gateway. It makes no sense to introduce yet another subnet 192.168.1.x into the situation.

Machine A needs to be told to do the routing and NAT for B.

With these keywords, please google for concrete steps, you will find an abundance of tutorials.